# How to create WearableRecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, wearables

How to create WearableRecyclerView in android wearable? I aware that in android devloper got information about it but it still small and i need full tutorial about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your main xml layout:

```xml
  <android.support.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/recycler_launcher_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

And use it like a regular RecyclerView i.e add an Adapter etc.